# parse out a substring from an index to the end of line

Tags: java, substring

Lets assume I have a String:

> "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
>   eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
>   minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
>   aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
>   reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse 
>   **Test Tag = a/b/c/d/e** cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui
>   officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

I want the substring `a/b/c/d/e`. (The a/b/c/d/e is a path that I need to parse out of the given string).

How do I get such a substring? I tried it with `str.subString()` and also using regex but couldn't get it.

Comment: `indexOf` and `substring`

Comment: What DID you get with subString and a regex?  You have a lot more than a/b/c/d/e after Test Tag= , so what is your criteria for determining that?

Comment: So what you want to match and what not? What are the criteria? What differentiates your `a/b/c/d/e` from the lorem ipsum text? the presence of `/` in it or something else? Please be specific here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
System.out.println(str.replaceAll(".*Test Tag =",""));
```

Well, this assumes with `anything` you really mean anything ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This allows an optional single space on either side of the equals sign, and captures all characters up through, but not including, the next space.

```
   import  java.util.regex.Pattern;
   import  java.util.regex.Matcher;
/**
   <P>{@code java BtwTestTagEqualsAndSpace}</P>
 **/
public class BtwTestTagEqualsAndSpace{
   public static final void main(String[] ignored)  {
      String sToSearch = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse Test Tag = a/b/c/d/e cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.";
      String sRplcWith = "$1";

      String sRegex = ".+Test Tag ?= ?([^ ]+).*$";
      Matcher m = Pattern.compile(sRegex).matcher(sToSearch);
      StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
      if(m.matches())  {
         System.out.println(m.group(1));
      }  else  {
         System.out.println("No match");
      }
   }
}
```

Output:

```
[C:\java_code\]java BtwTestTagEqualsAndSpace
a/b/c/d/e
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex

```
.*Test Tag\s?=\s?([^\s]+).*
```

Than you should fetch the group 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
str.subString(str.indexOf("=") + 2, str.indexOf("=") + 9)
```

Comment: The path a/b/c/d/e is not fixed. I need a generic solution.